# How do I remove "+ not at" from a style in Microsoft Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I set some tabstops, then later removed them and added some others. Now I want to create a style from the paragraph. When I click "new style", I get a line saying:

```
Tab stops:  1.9 cm, Right +  3.16 cm, Right + Not at  3.81 cm +  5.08 cm +  6.35 cm +  7.62 cm +  8.89 cm +  10.16 cm +  11.43 cm +  12.7 cm +  13.97 cm
```

The first part is fine, but I do not want to have the style apply the "not at" part in other places. How do I remove it from the style?

My Word version is 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check which style this style is 'based on'; that one still carries that tab at 3.81 cm.

1. you can either remove it from the other (base) style, or
2. base it on another style (or no style at all), or
3. add a tab in this style, so the text disappears (but then you have a tab there)

Comment: Thanks. I hadn't thought about a style being based on another. Setting it to based on no style solved it.